# Sign In won't Work

Tags: php, html

I have created a basic sign in form:

```
<form action = "" type = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "txt_user" placeholder = "Username" required/>
<input type = "password" name = "txt_pass" placeholder = "Password" required/>
<input type = "submit" name = "btn_submit" value = "  Sign In  ">
```

and posted this above my html:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
   $username = $_POST['txt_user'];
   echo $username;
?>
```

to see if the form works, it doesn't. The `txt_user` won't display up top the html as it should be but instead change my url from this: 
`localhost:8080/tryouts`

to this: 
`http://localhost:8080/tryout/?si_username=asd&si_password=asdasd&si_submit=++Sign+In++`

can you tell me what's going on? I tried this method before and it works. Maybe I misplaced something?

**Update** 
The page containing the form is called `signin.php` where it's been placed inside `index.php` like this:

```
<body>
<?php include("signin.php"); ?>

</body>
```

purpose of this is to save time and space for the php codes so that I won't be bother changing the sign in form from page to page, instead just changed the signin page main php page. I don't think it's causing this but still...

Comment: When the form data is passed in to the URL such as `?param=value&param2=value2` you should understand the form type is GET not POST. `<form>` should be attributed with `method` not type. I guess you confused it from AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `form method` to `POST`; `form type` is invalid. Right now, it's defaulting to using `GET`.

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "txt_user" placeholder = "Username" required/>
<input type = "password" name = "txt_pass" placeholder = "Password" required/>
<input type = "submit" name = "btn_submit" value = "  Sign In  ">
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)